# ¿Manera adecuada de almacenar roles, persona y usuario en una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Mi duda es la siguiente necesito diseñar una base de datos de la siguiente manera:

1. Tengo una tabla llamada "Roles" que almacena datos como: Administrador, Empleado, Cliente entre otros roles útiles para la empresa.
2. Tengo una tabla persona que almacena datos como nombres, apellidos, teléfono, entre otros datos necesarios para la empresa.
3. Tengo una tabla llamada "Usuarios" que contiene la llave foranea de persona, el usuario y contraseña.
4. Tengo una tabla de rompimiento de varios a varios llamada "Usuario_Rol" ya que un usuario puede ser cliente y trabajador al mismo tiempo, o a su vez administrador y cliente.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el siguiente si tengo esas relaciones mostradas en la imagen están bien o hay una forma mejor de hacerlas.

Supongamos que Alex es un cliente y Juan es el empleado que va a facturar, entonces antes de facturar se registra los datos de Alex en el sistema por el empleado Juan, entonces Alex solo esta en la tabla persona pero no tiene un usuario ni contraseña a diferencia de Juan.

Juan a su vez es un cliente ya que el tambien compra en el supermercado entonces como hago que Juan sea cliente y empleado a la vez, por eso pido me ayuden revisando la relación mostrada en la imagen.

Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: usa permisos para tus paginas con restricciones si un usuario accede a dicha pagina sin permisos necesita firmarse, tambien agrega un boton donde diga login, para que ya navegue con los permisos necesarios

Comment: Lo que pasa es que este sistema tiene un modulo de facturación, es decir si yo como un cliente voy y compro, los datos para la factura los genera el empleado pero mis datos ya se guardan en la base de datos, ya le modifico la pregunta con un gráfico para explicarme mejor

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta se está basada en opiniones y puede terminar cerrada. Sin embargo opino que en el propio planteamiento tienes la respuesta. Un usuario tiene atributos específicos que los defines en la tabla Usuarios. Evalúa si clientes y empleados también tienen atributos específicos y crea una tabla Clientes y otra Empleados con esos atributos específicos y relacionala con Persona tal como lo hiciste con usuarios.